# How to get stack trace from System.AccessViolationException?

Tags: c++-cli, stack-trace, unmanaged, access-violation, managed

I have a crash dump (minidump) for an applicaiton which includes managed and unmanaged code. The application crashed with exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException during execution of Delegate.DynamicInvoke. The inner exception is System.AccessViolationException but it doesn't include stack trace information (see below).

Is it possible to get this stack trace somehow?

Windbg output for !analyze -v (I've shortened the stack trace to make it more clear):

EXCEPTION_OBJECT: !pe 6c09b28

Exception object: 0000000006c09b28

Exception type:   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Message:          Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

InnerException:   System.AccessViolationException, Use !PrintException 0000000006c09988 to see more.

StackTrace (generated):

```
SP               IP               Function
00000000004FB540 0000000000000000 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)+0x1
00000000004FB540 000007FEF761D28C mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])+0x4c
00000000004FB5B0 000007FEF754FD3A mscorlib_ni!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])+0x6a
00000000004FB610 000007FE99A15010 CCTV_Framework_Utility!CCTV.Framework.Utility.EventsHelper.SafeInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])+0x60
```

StackTraceString: 
HResult: 80131604

EXCEPTION_OBJECT: !pe 6c09988

Exception object: 0000000006c09988

Exception type:   System.AccessViolationException

Message:          Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

InnerException:   none

StackTrace (generated): none

StackTraceString: none

HResult: 80004003

Comment: It is too late, the AVE was already caught and handled by the CLR.  The native stack was unwound so the stack trace is gonzo.  You probably can't get a debugger on that machine, use a tool like DebugDiag to trap the exception when it happens.